# New Hugo Post Not Displaying - RMarkdown/Blogdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

All,

I am working on creating a site to post some intro to R lessons. I'm using Blogdown to do so; however, the interface is quite confusing (I'm a data scientist, not a developer :) ). For some reason, when I `serve_site()`, both lesson 1 and lesson 2 show up under posts. Though, when I build the site and deploy by pushing to github, the post still isn't showing up.

It is hard to reproduce this... but here is the github link:
https://github.com/btbeal/Intro-To-R

here is the site:
https://zealous-hawking-ce0a3d.netlify.app/post/

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edited)When you post it to github to host, you want to only use the `public` folder, that's where blogdown renders your posts.

once you do that, your `index.html` will be the home page

looks like netlify updated finally

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think i am doing that. In the netlify settings, i have selected the public folder to pull from.

Comment: have you also tried `build_site()` sometimes for me that rerenders everything, and then `serve_site()` again

Comment: Yea, and in the serve_site() viewer pane it displays both... but not when I actually push to github? Seems like everything is in the public folder as it should be though.

Comment: I know it is difficult to diagnose - was hoping I was missing something simple!

Comment: yeah, what if you just try and create a lesson 3 and see if that renders? I don't want to host it to troubleshoot it, but willing to tinker with it in the viewer pane

Comment: So I posted a lesson 3, which rendered in the same manner. It posted then in the viewer then not on the site. Am looking more into the book currently. All good... Think it may have something to do with the YAML?

Comment: or I am wondering if it's a netlify not pulling the newest version of your repo?

Comment: Okay I fixed it: for some reason (and this may be coincidence), I added `output: blogdown::html_page` and it rendered.

Comment: damn, I should have caught that, good eye, no more rookie mistakes now

Comment: All good - not even sure that was correct but it worked! Thanks for your time, regardless. Two sets of eyes are better than one!

Comment: @BrennanBeal Hello i have the same problem, where exactly did  you added "output: blogdown::html_page" in which file please ? 
Thank you in advance.